# NServiceBus wire encryption during send to queue on another machine

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

I have a web service that:

- Uses MSMQ transport.
- Is a [send-only NSB endpoint](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/856305-one-way-send-only-endpoints).
- Uses NSB's [message encryption](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/894131-encryption-sample).
- Sends to a message queue on another machine.

Is the message encrypted during transport across the network to the message queue on the other machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all properties of type `WireEncryptedString` on a message are encrypted on the sender endpoint and then decrypted on the receiving endpoint.